# Cordova 3+ find all music files on device

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to learn Cordova, using visual studio as my ide. I've followed some instructions online to build a music player, but one plugin is missing... "Storage".

I tried running it anyway but I get 'error 5' when trying to use directoryReader.

I'm assuming this is due to a permission issue which again I assume would be sorted by the storage plugin.

A couple of questions here...

Are my above assumptions correct?
Where can I find the Storage Plugin?
How would I include the Plugin?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

*(I know I should post code but I'm not home now and this is driving me mad thinking about it!)*

Here's a sample of code I'm using:

```
document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );
    $('#readMusic').click(function () { readMusic(); });
};
function readMusic() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess, fail);
}
function readerSuccess(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        if (entries[i].name.indexOf('.mp3') > -1) {
            alert(entries[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the version 3.0 of the file plugin, it changed the `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT` path to be a path owned by the app, so it will be deleted on app uninstall and can't be accessed by other apps (as recommended by android best practises on storage)

If you want to keep using the old path, you have to add this line on your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it out and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cordova doesn't offer an official storage plugin per say. You can use localStorage to store values in the following way:

For saving: localStorage.setItem("key",value);

And for retrieving: localStorage.getItem("key");

However, it seems that your application is failing because it can not read information from your device's file system. Try this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

This plugin implements a File API allowing read/write access to files residing on the device.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, I had already started using the file plugin v3.0 that comes bundled with VS tools for cordova. The updated plugin you ponited me towards still does the same thing... No errors now, but the 'entries' on readerSuccess return 0 length.

Comment: Also, I have just checked that the fileSystem object returned from onFileSystemSuccess has: fileSystem.root.nativeURL: file:///data/data/io.cordova.myappb8ba7c/files/files/. Is this a sandbox environment for the app?